# How to check that a provided binary app version is the latest

Tags: go

I distribute my Go CLI app to users and now want to create a mechanism to offer an update to users if I create a new release/tag on Gitlab

How to check the source has a new version?

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/tags.html

Comment: it is unclear if you want runtime update, or just make them rebuild to the latest.

Comment: runtime update, same as zsh I think, when we open the terminal, it will ask us to update or not

Answer (score 0):

You could likely start with https://github.com/creativeprojects/go-selfupdate and add support for gitlab  by implementing [these 3 interfaces](https://github.com/creativeprojects/go-selfupdate/blob/7b16587034c3587376a358cd198a9301c81f2af2/source.go#L8-L32), e.g. using https://github.com/xanzy/go-gitlab to interact with gitlab.

The author of go-selfupdate already [stated they want to support gitlab anyway](https://github.com/creativeprojects/go-selfupdate/issues/3) so you could even contribute the gitlab support back and it will likely get accepted.

Comment: I'm not affiliated with any of these projects in any way, BTW. Just showcasing my google-fu.

Comment: If you can use GitHub or gitea instead of gitlab then there's nothing else to do because go-selfupdate already supports them out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

If your CLI is a developed in part or entirety as go-module *and it uses semantic version tags* then your latest release will propagate out to consumers of that module automatically when using https://pkg.go.dev/

For example take a look at the [github repository](https://github.com/ca-std/lib) of my go-module and notice how the latest stable release is [indexed by the go pkg reference](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ca-std/lib).

This happens auto-magically - read the docs on https://pkg.go.dev/

---

If you're asking how to properly distribute a binary to your users then best of luck with a custom implementation; you'd probably be better off packaging it as a snap or similar distribution framework.

Comment: does https://pkg.go.dev/ also work with private repo?